# Are local martingals always have locally integrable quadratic variation?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, local-martingales

I am reading the book: "P. Protter, Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations. Second edition, Springer-Verlag, (2004)",
where the following are mentioned:

(1) Local martingales are not always locally square integrable.

(2) A martingale $M$ is square integrable, namely, $\,\mathbb{E}(M_t^2)<\infty$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$, if and anly if $\,\,\mathbb{E}[M]_t<\infty\,$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$.

(3) Any local martingale is a special semimartingale.

On top of that, in the exercise part of Chap IV, it says as:

Exercise 1. A semimartingale $X$ is special if and only if the increasing process $[X]$ is locally integrable,
that is, there exists a sequence of stopping times $\,T_n\underset{n}{\nearrow}\infty$ a.s. such that $\,\mathbb{E}[X]_{T_n}<\infty$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I could not understand the assertion in Exercise 1.
If the assertion is correct,
given any local martingale $M$, which is a special semimartingale by (3),
we can choose a sequence of stopping times $S_n\le T_n$ which tends to $\infty$ a.s. and
which makes each $M_{\cdot\wedge S_n}$ martingale,
and hence $M_{\cdot\wedge S_n}$ becomes square integrable martingale by (2).
This contradicts to (1).

The assertion in Exercise 1 above implies that local martingales $M$ always have locally integrable quadratic variation (increasing process) $[M]$.

I would realy appreciate if you tell us what is correct and what is wrong in this argument.

Comment: I'm not sure how $M_{t \land S_n}$ being a martingale contradicts (1). Statement (1) is a statement about local martingales not always being locally square integrable. It is completely possible for a localised local martingale (e.g. $M_{t \land S_n}$, which is now a martingale) to be square integrable.

Comment: Suppose a local martingale is given. When a localized martingale is square integrable, i.e., there exists a sequence of stopping times such that the stopped process is sqare integrable martingale, we say the local martingale is locally square integrable, doesn't it ?